# Java XML Validation: Unable to resolve definitions from local XSD files

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, saml

I'm trying to validate xml, but I'm trying to do it without an internet connection. Therefore, I've tried to download all the XSD's that I need and change the imports to the local files, but it's unable to find a few definitions. Oddly enough, when I command+click on the offending line in IntelliJ, it takes me to the right local XSD.

I've written a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and posted it here: https://github.com/spearskw/testXsd

And here is the stack trace I get when I try to run it:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/kevin/repo/xsdTest/target/classes/schemas/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd; lineNumber: 32; columnNumber: 56; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4145)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1678)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDElementTraverser.java:170)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(XSDHandler.java:3618)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:633)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:575)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:541)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:638)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:670)
at testXsd.TestSchemaValidation.validateSaml(TestSchemaValidation.java:35)
at testXsd.TestSchemaValidation.main(TestSchemaValidation.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Answer (score 2):

As your schema references are in the classpath, you must provide a resource locator to the SchemaFactory:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        sf.setResourceResolver(new LocalSchemaLSResourceResolver());
```

Where the resolver is something like that:

```
public static class LocalSchemaLSResourceResolver implements LSResourceResolver{
    private static final String CARPETA_XSD = "META-INF/xsd/";

    //@Override
    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI)
    {

        try {
            LSInput input =  ((DOMImplementationLS)DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance().getDOMImplementation("LS")).createLSInput();
            input.setByteStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CARPETA_XSD+systemId.replace("../","")));

            return input;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw ExceptionWrapper.wrap(e,"Imposible encontrar importacion type=%, namespace=%, publicId=%, systemId=%, baseURI=%", type,namespaceURI, publicId, systemId, baseURI);
        }

    }
}
```

in your case you must replace "META-INF/xsd" by "schemas/".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried this though, and it still doesn't seem to work - I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: The "schemas/" directory must be in your classpath fo that the ContextClassLoader can find the resources